# Why is SVG Rendering so much worse than PNG Rendering?

Tags: javascript, html, image, svg

I compared two images in different browsers. The first one is an SVG image and the second one is a PNG image.

Here is the result:

[image]

[image]

I created a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/confile/2LL5M/

This is the code I use:

```
SVG Image <br>
<img width="300" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47067729/sticker2.svg">

<br><br>    
PNG Image  <br>   
<img width="250" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47067729/sticker.png">
```

Two problems occur:

1. the black edges of the SVG image are not scaled correctly they appear much thinner than they should be after scaling
2. the PNG image has much better quality. The rendering is much smoother the the edges appear strong and sharp. The SVG image has poor quality with fuzzy edges

I use Adobe Illustrator to export the PNG from the SVG.

**How can I increase the quality for SVG images on Chrome/FF/Safari?**

Comment: So... whatever created the PNG image from the SVG scaled the black edges differently to the browser. What converted it?

Comment: @JakeGould Chrome/FF/Safari

Comment: @Popnoodles I use Adobe Illustrator to export the PNG from the SVG.

Comment: This person has done some research and made some comments http://opticalcortex.com/svg-rendering-in-browsers/

Comment: The browsers will be rendering the SVG correctly.  Popnoodles is right. Whatever generated the PNG either has a bug, or was rendering a version of the file with thicker lines.  Please tell us how the PNG was generated.

Comment: @BigBadaboom The PNG was exported with Adobe Illustrator.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say why Adobe Illustrator uses such thicker lines for PNG than SVG.  AI uses their proprietary document format internally, so converting to either PNG or SVG will result in some subtle changes.

However, for the simple question of how to make the SVG file look more like the PNG, just go back into your editor, select everything, and set a larger stroke width.  If you still find that the lines are fuzzy, you could set `shape-rendering:crispEdges;` in your CSS, but be aware that this turns off anti-aliasing completely, resulting in jagged edges to your diagonal lines.